# "PANIC: early exception 08 rip 246:10" error  with an Nvidia 210G

Tags: nvidia, graphics, pcie

I have a Nvidia 210 graphics card and have gone in to text mode in Ubuntu and disabled the standard driver and replaced it with the new driver I got from Nvidia's website. Everything works fine but when the computer is off for more then a few hours, the next time I boot I get a weird error message:

```
PANIC: early exception 08 rip 246:10 error
```

At this point I have to take out my new card and drop in a 8500GT card, go back into text mode and re-install the drivers to get my new card to work again. This message even comes up if I try to go into recovery mode before re-installing the drivers. The 8500GT card I can pop-in at anytime and it works no problem with any Nvidia driver installed. Anyone have any clue why this is happening and what to do to fix it???

- Dell Inspiron 530
- Intel Core 2 Quad 2.33Ghz
- 3 GB Mem  1TB HDD
- Nvidia 210G or Nvidia 8500GT PCIe1

Comment: Have you done a memory test?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a hardware problem. Someone else fixed it [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1796145) with a hardware-related thing.